# Dagger2 can not provide dependancy

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I try to use Dagger2 in Kotlin but getting this error

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]
>   [com.syouth.tsarz.base.BaseComponent.getNavigationManager()]
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be provided without an
>   @Provides-annotated method.

I'm really confused because I've provided FragmentManager in my module:

```
@Module
class BaseModule {

    @Provides
    @BaseScope
    fun provideFragmentManager(activity: FragmentActivity): FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

}
```

Here is my component:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [(BaseModule::class)])
@BaseScope
interface BaseComponent {

    fun getNavigationManager(): NavigationManager

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun activity(activity: FragmentActivity): Builder

        fun build(): BaseComponent
    }
}
```

Navigation manager is injected by using an @Inject constructor and class in annotated with @BaseScope

So basically I just try to get a dependency through a component which should be perfectly ok.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Was using wrong annotation in scopes definition.

Comment: Though I'm glad you were able to find a solution, I think that adding a little detail about your solution (which scopes? where were they defined? how could you tell? etc) would help your answer give more benefit to future readers. Cheers!